# Regex Expression: Getting all data until next match

Tags: regex

so I have a few different strings like:

```
1. remove #someEntry set #someKey = :someValue
2. set #someOtherKey = :someOtherValue
```

I want some regex expression which gives me everthing after a remove, set, add or delete until either the end of the string if it is the last match or until the next (remove, set, add, delete).

So I tried the following regex:
`(?:(set|remove|add|delete).*((?=set|remove|add|delete)))`

But this will only return `remove #someEntry`  for the 1. line, but nothing for the 2. line.
I am trying around with Regex, but I cant find I search for :(

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:set|remove|add|delete)\s*(.*?)\s*((?=(?:set|remove|add|delete)|$))` https://regex101.com/r/OMzlxD/1

Comment: Thanks, was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put the capturing group around the alternatives, but around the part that you want to capture to refer to it.

You can match any of the alternatives followed by optional whitespace chars. Then capture in group on as least as possible chars except a newline until you can assert what is on the right is 0+ whitespace chars followed by any of the alternatives or the end of the string `$`

Use a word boundary `\b` to prevent the words being part of a larger word.

```
\b(?:set|remove|add|delete)\b\s*(.*?)\s*((?=\b(?:set|remove|add|delete)\b|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1LVUQs/1)